# Checking if a a list exists in another list of lists

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a tic tac toe app and I'm currently trying to figure out how to let the computer know that the user has won.

My approach is to append each position the user has taken onto the "x_moves" list, and to check that against the "win_if" list to see if the x_moves list contains any combination in any order.

```
win_if = (
["top_l", "top_m", "top_r"],
["mid_l", "mid_m", "mid_r"], 
["bot_l", "bot_m", "bot_r"],
["top_l", "mid_l", "bot_l"], 
["top_m", "mid_m", "bot_m"], 
["top_r", "mid_r", "bot_r"],
["top_l", "mid_m", "bot_r"], 
["top_r", "mid_m", "bot_l"]
)

x_moves = ["top_m", "mid_r", "mid_m", "bot_m"]
```

I've tried using "in", however this doesn't work because the x_moves list needs to be in a very particular order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take each inner list in `win_if` and check if users' moves in the inner or not. And if count is bigger than `2` (or equal to 3), it means there is winner. Something like this:

```
win_if = (
    ["top_l", "top_m", "top_r"],
    ["mid_l", "mid_m", "mid_r"],
    ["bot_l", "bot_m", "bot_r"],
    ["top_l", "mid_l", "bot_l"],
    ["top_m", "mid_m", "bot_m"],
    ["top_r", "mid_r", "bot_r"],
    ["top_l", "mid_m", "bot_r"],
    ["top_r", "mid_m", "bot_l"]
)

x_moves = ["top_m", "mid_r", "mid_m", "bot_m"]

for inner in win_if:
    count = 0
    for each in x_moves:
        if each in inner:
            count += 1
    if count > 2:
        print("winner")
        break
```

Comment: Thank you, this such a great solution

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad it is useful. Just small note; I have edited and added `break` after finding winner not to lose time and resource.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could write a simple function like:

EDIT: You may use [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to achieve your result.

```py
def is_winner(test):
    win_if = [
        {"top_l", "top_m", "top_r"},
        {"mid_l", "mid_m", "mid_r"}, 
        {"bot_l", "bot_m", "bot_r"},
        {"top_l", "mid_l", "bot_l"}, 
        {"top_m", "mid_m", "bot_m"}, 
        {"top_r", "mid_r", "bot_r"},
        {"top_l", "mid_m", "bot_r"}, 
        {"top_r", "mid_m", "bot_l"}
    ]

    for win_possibility in win_if:

        if set(test) == win_possibility:
            return True
    return False
```

Does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The problem here is that the x_moves list is not necessarily in the same order as the lists in win_if. So if I input "print(is_winner(["top_l", "top_m", "mid_l", "top_r"]))", it will not count as a win

Comment: No need to apologise, I appreciate you time. Thank you :)

Comment: I have edited the answer. Maybe it now works for you

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to represent the board as a 2D Matrix like this

```
board = [[1, 2, 3], ['o', 'o', 'o'], [7, 8, 9]]
player_1 = 'x'
player_2 = 'o'
winner = None

# checks rows
def check_rows(board):
    for i in range(3):
        if board[i].count(board[i][0]) == len(board[i]):
            if board[i][0] == player_1:
                return 'player_1'
            elif board[i][0] == player_2:
                return 'player_2'
    return None

column = [[board[i][j] for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
diagonal_1 = [board[i][j] for i, j in enumerate(range(3))]
diagonal_2 = [board[i][j] for i, j in enumerate(range(2, -1, -1))]
winner = check_rows(board) or check_rows(column) or check_rows(diagonal_1) or check_rows(diagonal_2)
print(winner)
```

this would return None, if there is no winner at this state of the board, it's very compact, and only uses one function for the rows, columns, and the diagonals.

`board[i].count(board[i][0]) == len(board[i])` checks if all the 3 items in a row in the matrix are equal, that means one of the two players won, so then we check which one won, by checking the first item in the row (since they're all equal anyways) and returns the player that won in a string.